# Can I run NixOS in an LXC container?

Tags: lxc, nixos

Can I run NixOS in an LXC container?

To run debian on top of debian, one would use

```
LANG=C SUITE=jessie MIRROR=http://httpredir.debian.org/debian lxc-create -n debian8 -t debian
```

What should one do if he wants to run nixos on top of debian?

Comment: I'd have the ask why you would want to do that. The point behind the debian thing is that your app my use some libraries/commands that are debian-specific. Other than that it's just a generic GNU/Linux image. NixOS is already pretty niche so it's hard to imagine you really need it to run in a container.

Comment: @Bratchley I want a "normal" host with a minimal easy to replace guest

Comment: I don't think Debian ships with predefined `lxc-create` templates for NixOS, but you should be able to create the LXC root yourself. Eg: With `nixos-install`

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/9735

Comment: @Bratchley I suppose a valid use case could be having some hard dependency on a particular host distro (e.g. binary drivers working only Ubuntu) but want to configure the services like Postgres in the declarative way provided by NixOS

Answer (score 1):

It appears you can deploy a nixos configuration to [libvirt with nixops](http://nixos.org/nixops/manual/#idm140737318778912) (see the deployment.libvirtd.. attributes). I've only used nixops to deploy to virtualbox myself but if it's anything like that you should find it pretty straightforward to use.

Comment: Unluckily the libvirt backend is currently support only by nixops on NixOS (section 3.8. Deploying to Libvirtd of the https://nixos.org/nixops/manual/)